# Spring boot - parachute is non existent error

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 1.1.6 in our application. Its running for a while without any issues and started throwing the following error all of sudden.

SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.

I tried setting -Xms and -Xmx to the higher value. But still getting the same error. Is there any setting i am missing.

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Comment: I got the same error a while ago and resolved it with setting -XX:MaxPermSize to a higher value. But I don't know if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Sounds like you have a memory leak. You should use a profiler or heap analyser to help you diagnose what's leaking and why.

Comment: I get this error in few mins after starting my application. This app works fine in test environment. I have this issue only in my local eclipse setup.

Comment: Adding -XX:MaxPermSize to a higher value solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding -XX:MaxPermSize to a higher value solved the problem.

Comment: I have set that as 4096m even then this issue is persistent. What value did you specify?